# Is there a difference when to use with() with an array or a string as parameter?

Tags: laravel

It was brought to my attention in a code review, instead of:

**Version A:** `$someModel->with('relationMethodA.id,some_field, created_at')`

rather use this notation:

**Version B** `$someModel->with(['relationMethodA' => fn($q) => $q->select('relationMethodA.id,some_field, created_at')])`.

I wonder because both give the same result. Are there any reasons to use one or the other?

Comment: It's the same and It's a minified version of the second one. Like a short `if` statement

Answer (score 2):

When eager loading, the first syntax you illustrated should use a colon;

```
$someModel->with('relationMethodA:id,some_field, created_at')
```

So this loads just three of the columns and is the same as adding a select statement to the relationship, as you did in the second example

Note that you can also pass an array of related models;

```
$someModel->with(['relationA', 'relationB','relationC']);
```

as well as just passing multiple parameters

```
$someModel->with('relationA', 'relationB','relationC');
```

and nested relations

```
$someModel->with('relationA.subrelation','relationB');
```

personally, I would always use the colon to specify the columns to load as this is far more concise and readable than the closure approach, although this can be useful for adding additional conditions or even query scopes.

Answer (score 1):

As what document said in [Constraining Eager Loads](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/eloquent-relationships)

> Sometimes you may wish to eager load a relationship but also specify additional query conditions for the eager loading query. You can accomplish this by passing an array of relationships to the with method where the array key is a relationship name and the array value is a closure that adds additional constraints to the eager loading query:

You can see in the official document example:

```php
use App\Models\User;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Database\Eloquent\Builder;
 
$users = User::with(['posts' => function (Builder $query) {
    $query->where('title', 'like', '%code%');
}])->get();
```

Only those posts with the word `code` in their title will load for each user.

```php
$someModel->with(['relationMethodA' => fn($q) => $q->select('relationMethodA.id,some_field, created_at')])
```

This will load the relation  "**relationMethodA**" with this specific columns only:
'relationMethodA.id,some_field, created_at', However **Version A** will load all columns. This might be a good option when you don't need whole data in your relations.

Comment: Wrong. Still, you can get a specific column by using `:`  end of the relationship. `user:name,email`

Comment: The point is you can add everything to your query, not only select. I've added an example for clarification.

Answer (score 1):

Well, Indeed both queries return the same result but there's very slight and neglible perfromance measure which makes Version A to be faster.
However Version B will allow you to add more complexity in the query.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Can you please explain why the variant is faster?